# Notify OSD through wine

Tags: wine, notify-osd

Is there a way of making wine use the default ubuntu 10.10 notification b
Bubble (which I think it is called notify OSD) instead of the classic bubble that wine uses.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be very difficult (But doable). The reason for this is:

- Ubuntu 10.10 has not had support since April 2012
- Notify OSD is something related mostly to Ubuntu which means the Wine developers or somebody (a 3rd party) would need to code this function into Wine, which probably would not get into the main development of Wine since wine is for all Linux versions, not just Ubuntu.
- Wine is more focused on features and fixes related to the workings of Windows. So something like this would get classified as a wishlist.
- Some might even argue that giving Wine the option to access stuff like the notification bubble would include security issues. The same people might also agree that it would be easier to do the task that needs Wine in Linux using an alternative (eg: Like instead of using Photoshop to send the notification bubble, use Gimp which has scripting features).

Is it possible to do this? Yes it is.

Would it get added into the main Wine or Ubuntu development? Most likely not.

Can a developer do this? Yes. As a patch for Wine that works on Ubuntu and redirects the messages from Wine to the Ubuntu notification system.

So as you can see it is tough (Not that tough if one follows the code for it) but doable.

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone had it figured out. So is there anyone that can make a patch for this. - thanks for the help